# In ambari install options should I add Ambari-Server IP/hostname?

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I'm newbie to ambari, I followed [hortronworks](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/introducing-apache-ambari-deploying-managing-apache-hadoop/#setup-ambari) tutorial on how to install ambari. My question is in the step of **install options**, should I set hostname of **server and agent** or just agent? (because when I set only the agent It pass otherwise it fail!)

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give the **IPs of all the nodes/hosts.**

If its not working on your Server node then its mostly because your [ssh authorized_key](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.2.2.0/bk_Installing_HDP_AMB/content/_set_up_password-less_ssh.html) step wasn't completed on that node.

Do `cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys` on your Server node(in the `.ssh` dir).

*(Do not touch any other ssh keys)*

Try to ssh to your Server node from the same node. If it works without a password then you have fixed it.

Comment: ok, thank you for responding, so, I can Add server and agent host **even** if ambari agent isn't installed in the server node, is that right ?

Comment: @aName you don't have to install Amabri agent on any node manually, Ambari Server would install it automatically once you click on **register and confirm**.

Comment: because in the install options, when you enter your target hosts, a popup appears and it says : **You must install Ambari Agents on each host you want to manage before you proceed.**

Comment: I haven't installed Ambari agent manually in my clusters. There is no harm doing it though, because **it gets installed automatically** anyway.